# Less formal synonym for "individual"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm creating a service with two tiers - one for individuals, and one for businesses. Advertising material will be split into two sections of information, which will be titled "For individuals", and "For businesses".

The problem is that I need another synonym to describe individuals, as "individuals" to me sounds too formal and not appealing enough, and the problem gets worse (and a bit philosophical) when going down the list of synonyms:

[image]

Compound words would be fine, I'm just looking for whatever sounds best. It may even be that "individual" *is* the best word in this context, which I'm happy to accept if no better words come along.

Comment: "For individuals" and "for businesses" is a pretty common way to distinguish services here in Australia.

Comment: "Personal, "home", or "consumer" might prove handy.

Comment: You might consider "enterprise" for the business section.

Comment: Advertising is evil. The purpose of this list is not to further this.

Comment: @David I hope that was sarcasm.

Comment: What about ...for people and businesses...?

Comment: In fact, business classified as sole-trading, partnership, joint stock company, cooperative societies, etc. are also considered individuals in the eyes of law.  A company is known as an 'artificial legal person'. https://www.lawteacher.net/free-law-essays/business-law/a-company-law-essays.php;

Comment: @RamPillai, actually, while the word *person*, in legal contexts, covers corporations, the word *individual* is only rarely so used; its use is, even in legal contexts, usually limited to natural persons. This makes *individual* preferable to *person* for the OP's purposes.

Comment: Yeah, agree @jsw29

Comment: 'The list of synonyms' sounds like it was presented by the Archangel Gabriel. While he would be unlikely to sue for breach of copyright, an attributed link to where this particular list was actually borrowed from is advisable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's a standard list of synonyms as provided by all the big online dictionaries, but I believe this particular one was from [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com).

Comment: ELU **requires** that attributed links be given alongside any quotes. Not in comments. There really are copyright issues (and quite rightly). // It's certainly not the one given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/individual).

Comment: *"individuals" to me sounds too formal and not appealing enough"* You have every right to judge how much it appeals to your readers, and even to judge whether it is too informal for them. But *individual* is not in any way particularly formal, including, or especially, in the context as you describe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Person* is on the right track, except that it's singular. (And *personal* is adjectival.)

If you want to maintain parallelism (and informality), use something like this:

> Company slogans are *for businesses* and personal mottos are *for* ***people***.

Comment: For Persons* / For Businesses, is possible but *persons* is even more formal than individual ^^

Comment: 'Dudes' is less formal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Don't forget dudettes!

Comment: +1, it's very common to see access tiers of *Personal* and *Professional* in software editions or subscriptions.